# SQL for a Common Table Expression for List of Values with sort order?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a common table expression with the following SQL:

```
SELECT 'ISSUE_PRIORITY' COL_NAME, 'Issue Priority' DESCRIPTION, 1 SORT_ORDER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'START_DATE', 'Start Date', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'COMPLETION_DATE', 'Complete Date', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'KEY_PARTNERS', 'Key Partners', 4 FROM DUAL
```

Which generates output similar to:

```
COL_NAME           DESCRIPTION       SORT_ORDER
ISSUE_PRIORITY     Issue Priority             1
START_DATE         Start Date                 2
COMPLETION_DATE    Complete Date              3
KEY_PARTNERS       Key Partners               4
```

Is there a way to generate the SORT_ORDER column, rather than explicitly specifying its values, based on the order in which I am constructing the CTE?

Comment: I don't think so. You may be tempted to use SEQUENCE but generaly speaking optimizer is free to execute UNION ALL in any order,

Comment: No. Order is only guaranteed with explicitly stated ordering criteria

Answer (score 0):

A way to make the numbering is by using the `DENSE RANK` function.  For my example, I'm going to pretend your table exists:

```
SELECT col_name, description, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col_name) AS sort_order
FROM [table_name];
```

Here are the results of that query:

```
COL_NAME             DESCRIPTION        SORT_ORDER
 COMPLETION_DATE      Complete Date      1
 ISSUE_PRIORITY       Issue Priority     2
 KEY_PARTNERS         Key Partners       3
 START_DATE           Start Date         4
```

Comment: I would need the order to be ISSUE_PRIORITY, START_DATE, COMPLETION_DATE, KEY_PARTNERS.

Comment: @dave - This answer is incorrect; the row order in the database is not promised or guaranteed. This is specifically one of the features of "relational" databases. There is no way to force row ordering, short of what you are already doing.